# Display Warning popup while entering a new page after the new page is rendered in oracle adf

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have a requirement to show a warning popup while navigating from a page to another page  . The warning popup should be displayed when the second page is rendered based on the value of a binding(whether the binding has any value (rendered=true)
 or is null(rendered=false)).How can i implement it such a way that the popup would be displayed when the second page is rendered itself?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming few things:
1) By page you mean fragment.
2) You are on JDev 12c +.

This is something you may refer to:
[execute code on fragment load](https://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2013/09/call-method-on-page-load-of-jsff-jsf-fragment-in-oracle-adf.html)
This tells you how to register a ControllerClass for your fragment page definition, and get hold of your phase Id.
You may also directly work with regionContext.getRefreshFlag().

However, please note that this code will fire for every request you make from that fragment. So once you close the warning popup, you should set a page-flow parameter which would prevent the popup from opening further.

For 11g releases, this functionality can be achieved by using the invokeAction binding to call a managed bean method, and setting the refresh condition as prepareRender.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a  showPopupBehaviour in the Form and make the TrigerType="load"

follow the follow this link : http://prabhat-java.blogspot.ae/2015/10/displaying-popup-on-page-load.html